# How can I control new windows in GeckoFX (C#)

Tags: c#, automation, popup, geckofx

I am working on web automation project using GeckoFX and I have encountered an obstacle that I cannot get through by myself.

There are some similar questions around here, but no one of them is answered, so I will try to explain my problem as good as I can.

When I open a "target=_blank" link, a new window automatically pops up (by default)
I need to get control over it (e.g. resize).

I have tried to use CreateWindow event, which allowed me to cancel the popup. 
However, when I try to access the Webbrowser inside the popup by using Eventargs, everything just freezes and that's the end.

Here's the code, that I used:

```
void GeckoWB_CreateWindow2(object sender, GeckoCreateWindow2EventArgs e)
{
    //This example works
    e.Cancel = true;

    //and this doesn't
    //e.WebBrowser.Navigate(e.Uri);
}
```

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.InitialWidth and e.InitialHeight to control the size of the new window.

```
     private void browser_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
     {
         // Full Screen
         Rectangle rect = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
         e.InitialWidth = rect.Width;            
         e.InitialHeight = rect.Height;           

     }
```